# Default of routing url is wrong in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am learning angular 4 , I am trying to create an application where the landing /home page will show a "welcome" message . And it will have two tabs "home and products" and on clicking product tab it will show list of products

I have implemented it only one issue I am facing is the default url always takes productlist, and it shows list of products on home page after refreshing .

[image: default productList]

app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { productListComp } from './product.list';
import { homeComp } from './home.comp';
const routes : Routes=[
{path:"",redirectTo:"/home",pathMatch:"full"},
{path:"home",component:homeComp},
{path:"productList",component:productListComp}
];
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
productListComp,
homeComp
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
providers: [
  ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private _router : Router)
{
}
productListSel(){
console.log("in productListSel");
this._router.navigate(['productList']);
}

homeSel(){
console.log("in homeSel");
this._router.navigate(['home']);
}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" 
   (click)="homeSel()">home</a>    </li>
   <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" 
   (click)="productListSel()">products</a>    </li>

</ul>
```

If I click on the home tab then it shows proper "Welcome" msg , but if I just do "ng serve -o" or refresh the page always productList shows.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: post your routing module code

Comment: @Sajeetharan Route setup is already there.

Comment: Your code works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yugk5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html without any issues. Only thing that I see missing in your code is `router-outlet` tag

Comment: @Amit , it's there...

Comment: yeah your code works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your routes, such as;

```
   const routes : Routes=[
    {path:"",redirectTo:"/home",pathMatch:"full"},**strong text**
    {path:"home",component:homeComp},
    {path:"productList",component:productListComp},
    {path: '**', component: homeComp }  ==> Added
];
```